# Simple ACL not working

Tags: networking, cisco, access-control-list

Network: Cisco 2921. Two subnets.  192.168.1.0/24 and 2.0/24.

For some reason I can't get inter-subnet communication.

I bound an ACL with the following statements to the inbound interface of each subnet.

On Gi0/0 (1.0/24) I applied  "access-list 101 permit ip 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255 any" to the inbound interface.

On Gi0/1 (2.0/24) I applied "access-list 102 permit ip 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any" to the inbound interface.

When I did these, DHCP stopped working, as did internet sometimes so I deleted them.

I did this in packet-tracer and it worked 100%.  Why is it not working on the real router?

Running Config:

```
Current configuration : 2608 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 15:22:51 UTC Mon Feb 18 2013
! NVRAM config last updated at 17:41:03 UTC Sun Feb 17 2013
! NVRAM config last updated at 17:41:03 UTC Sun Feb 17 2013
version 15.1
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
enable secret 5 xxxxxx
enable password xxxxxx
!
no aaa new-model
!
no ipv6 cef
ip source-route
ip cef
!
!
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.2.1
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.2.1 192.168.2.99
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.2.1 192.168.2.50
!
ip dhcp pool DHCP_POOL
 network 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.2.1
 dns-server 8.8.8.8
 domain-name subnet2.local
!
!
ip name-server 8.8.8.8
ip name-server 8.8.4.4
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
crypto pki token default removal timeout 0
!
!
voice-card 0
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2921/K9 sn FTX1703AHBN
hw-module pvdm 0/0
!
!
!
!
redundancy
!
!
ip ftp username xxxxxxx
ip ftp password xxxxx
!
!
!
!
interface Embedded-Service-Engine0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
 ip access-group 5 out
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 no mop enabled
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 ip address xxxxxxxxxxx 255.255.255.248
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
ip nat inside source list 1 interface GigabitEthernet0/2 overload
ip nat inside source list 2 interface GigabitEthernet0/2 overload
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 108.162.28.169
ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 GigabitEthernet0/0
ip route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 GigabitEthernet0/1
!
access-list 1 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 2 permit 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 3 permit 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 3 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 4 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 5 permit any
access-list 101 permit ip 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255 any
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
mgcp profile default
!
!
!
!
!
gatekeeper
 shutdown
!
!
!
line con 0
line aux 0
line 2
 no activation-character
 no exec
 transport preferred none
 transport input all
 transport output pad telnet rlogin lapb-ta mop udptn v120 ssh
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 password ********
 login
 transport input all
!
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are mixing the concept of Inbound and Outbound in your ACL.

If Interface GigabitEthernet0/0 has the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet behind it, then to allow that traffic to go on the other interface you will add the following ACL on GigabitEthernet0/0 and vice versa.

> access-list 101 permit ip 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any
>
> access-list 102 permit ip 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255 any

The same thing could be achieved (and would be more secure) by restricting where the traffic can go.

> access-list 101 permit ip any 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255
>
> access-list 102 permit ip any 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255

If you use the above ACL, then both network behind both interfaces will only be able to talk to each other...that's it.

Then in the GigabitEthernet0/0 cofiguration:

> ip access-group 101 in

And on the GigabitEthernet0/1:

> ip access-group 102 in

Inbound and Outbound is always based on what interface the packet will hit first.

To better understand when dealing with ACL and the Inbound/Outbound issue, pretend you are the Router and/or Firewall.

**Do you (the router) allow packets coming to you with IP 192.168.1.10 on YOUR interface Gi0/0?**

Yes I do, ACLs on that interface allows it;

> access-list 101 permit ip 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any

or

> access-list 101 permit ip any 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255

If you had your ACL set on Outbound, the question would be;

**Do you allow packets from 192.168.1.10 to leave YOUR interface Gi0/0?**

Once you allowed that traffic, you don't need to add ACLs on the destination interface when both of them are on the same device.

Comment: Well now I'm definitely confused... You are correct Gi0/0 has the 1.0/24 subnet connected to it.  Why would I have to allow access its own subnet?

Comment: You are not, you are telling Gi0/0 to let traffic FROM 192.168.1.0/24 to "traverse" Gi0/0. The last line in my answer is the key...when 192.168.1.10 wants to talk to 192.168.2.10, the first interface in the way is Gi0/0, your ACL determines whether it's allow to pass or not. Once it traversed Gi0/0, you do not have to have an ACL allowing it to go on Gi0/1.

Comment: Thanks man, I'll try this on the weekend when I can take the network down.